# How to change textures (separately) of a mesh multiple times imported from Blender? (Babylon.js)

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

I imported a mesh from Blender three times and I put different ID for each one and then I try to change the texture just for one mesh with:

```
var newMesh = scene.getMeshByID("first_id");
newMesh.material.diffuseTexture = new BABYLON.Texture("colors/blue01.jpg", scene);
```

But even if each mesh have a unique ID (I can see it with console.log(newMesh.id)) all the three meshes change their textures.

How can I fix it to change the texture only for one mesh separate from others?

Sorry for my english.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to affect a new material to all meshes. By default they should share the same.

Here is an example of multiple materials on multiple meshes: https://www.babylonjs-playground.com?4